# Polling every certain interval in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how can you poll for example every 2 minutes inside a web application? I'm looking for something similar to a timer in winforms.

The poller class would be a singleton in the app (I use a container to handle lifecyles) and I'm also aware about the lifecycle of objects inside a webapp.

Comment: Long back, I've read this article  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

Comment: No such thing.. for more info see http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Server side or client side?

Answer (score 6):

Web app code is not intended to run continuously for an indefinite time. It can be shut down or recycled by IIS based on various conditions multiple times an hour.

Better approach is to write a windows service or use scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options.  SignalR is a great framework to solve the polling problem that will gracefully fall back from WebSockets to Long Polling based on the support provided by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options in JS

```
// easy
function run() {
   // do stuff
}
setInterval(run, 120000)

// safer
function run() {
   // do stuff
  setTimout(run, 120000);
}
setTimout(run, 120000);
```

http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 0):

set meta http-equiv refresh to the desired seconds in the .aspx page, the page will auto refresh as defined and you can update , for eg., Label.Text=DateTime.Now.Tostring(), to show the time. but as mentioned above its not always good practice to do this. for partial rendering you may rely on AJAX update panel

Answer (score 0):

[WebBackgrounder](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder) if you have small scale needs (this is easy to set up // minimal infrastructure).

Windows Service / [Worker Role](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morebits/archive/2011/01/01/building-windows-azure-service-part5-worker-role-background-tasks-handler.aspx) / [Console App (that is executed as a periodic task)](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/03/09/screencast-using-background-workers-on-appharbor) for serious work.